# Remove the parent folder from the domain in the routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following resources`:

```
resources :badges do
    collections do
        match 'create', via [:get, :post]
    end
end
```

When I access these pages I always get something like `[mydomain]/badges/new`.

How do I remove the `badges` fromt the domain and maintain the clean `resources` routing method? (without having to manually change all of these resources' paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
resources :badges, path: '/' do
  #...
end
```